# Use Java object as Clojure map

Tags: java, clojure, clojure-java-interop

I have a Java class that I'd like to use in Clojure.  But, I want to use it as a Clojure map.  What are the steps required to do so?

I've looked at the code for `IPersistentMap` -- should the Java class implement that?  Or should there be some Clojure code which implements a protocol?

I know I could just write some mapping code, to explicitly convert the code from Java objects to maps, but that solution has a high effort/reward ratio.  Also, I might encounter this same situation many more times.

---

Concrete example:  I have a parser written in Java.  I'd like to use that to parse some text, and then access the contents of the parsed data structure as though it were in Clojure maps:

```
(def parser (new MyParser))

(let [parse-tree (parser ... parse some text ...)]
  ((parse-tree :items) "itemid"))
```

Answer (score 24, accepted):

The function [`bean`](http://clojuredocs.org/clojure_core/clojure.core/bean) came to mind:

> Takes a Java object and returns a read-only implementation of the map abstraction based upon its JavaBean properties.

Example taken from the site:

```
user=> (import java.util.Date)
java.util.Date

user=> (def *now* (Date.))
#'user/*now*

user=> (bean *now*)
{:seconds 57, :date 13, :class java.util.Date,
 :minutes 55, :hours 17, :year 110, :timezoneOffset -330,
 :month 6, :day 2, :time 1279023957492}
```

Comment: This looks promising, I will give it a try.  I may have to do a recursive `bean` application.

Comment: Have a look at clojure.java.data. There is a function (from-java) that uses java.beans.Introspector recursively. Furthermore, you can refine the output of from-java by adding ...BeanInfo classes to a java library to control which get... methods are recognised, and to rename the keywords that are used in the clojure map.

Comment: Now you can also try bean-dip and similar libraries: https://github.com/uwcpdx/bean-dip/ (I'm the author of former but describe latter in the README)

Answer (score 5):

Sure the `(bean javaObject)` (see [bean ClojureDoc](http://clojuredocs.org/clojure_core/clojure.core/bean)) works well, but it doesn't let you select the property you want and those you doesn't. It has impact when you input the resulting map into the `json-str` function, in that case you can get an error saying : "Don't know how to write JSON of ..."

And I find that annoying when I deal with NoSQL DB (mongoDB, neo4j) that accepts essentially JSON (like the underlying of [neocons](https://github.com/michaelklishin/neocons)).

So what's my solution?

```lisp
(defmacro get-map-from-object-props [object & props]
  ;->> will eval and reorder the next list starting from the end
  (->> (identity props) ;identity is here to return the 'props' seq
       ;map each property with their name as key and the java object invocation as the value
       ;the ~@ is here to unsplice the few properties
       (map (fn [prop] [(keyword (str prop)) `(.. ~object ~@(prop-symbol prop) )]))
       (into {})))

;getter is a simple function that transform a property name to its getter "name" -> "getName"
(defn prop-symbol [prop]
  (map symbol (map getter (clojure.string/split (str prop) #"\\."))))
```

And you can use it like that (yes the function takes care of a chain of property if any)

```lisp
(get-map-from-object-props javaObject property1 property2 property3.property1)
```

Hope that will help someone...

Answer (score 1):

Clojure keywords can look up stuff in anything that implements the required (read-only) parts of the java.lang.Map interface. The problem is probably going to be that you're not actually using clojure keywords as keys so that might not help you.

As for IPersistentMap; your parser presumably doesn't implement anything relevant to the that interface.

Personally, I'd write a straight up conversion function. Clojure uses a lot of those (seq, for instance) and after converting, you *know* you're dealing with a real persistent map and not something that only acts like it some of the time (so you can actually call seq, keys, vals etc on it).

Alternatively;

- just implement clojure.lang.ILookup, and leave out everything else.
- convert using some generated/reflection code if you want something more generic. See https://github.com/joodie/clj-java-fields for an example.

Comment: I edited my example to show that I want to treat the parse *result* as a Clojure map.  I have no problem making all the fields in the parse result `final`, if that helps any.

Answer (score 1):

What about just using a java.util.HashMap with (interned) strings as keys, and doing the conversion in a few lines of Clojure ?:

```
(into {} (java.util.HashMap. {"foo" "bar" "baz" "quux"})) ?

{"foo" "bar" "baz" "quux"}
```

or with keywords:

```
(into {}
  (map
    (juxt
      #(keyword (key %))
      #(val %))
    (java.util.HashMap. {"foo" "bar" "baz" "quux"})))

{:baz "quux", :foo "bar"}
```

Comment: I don't see how to use this ... I have a Java class already, and want to use it as though it were a Clojure object .... are you suggesting that I convert my java object to a HashMap?

Answer (score 0):

`bean` works fine, but it does not handle some Java objects very well.

```
(import java.awt.Insets)
(bean (Insets. 1 2 3 4))
=> {:class java.awt.Insets}
```

but there is a java solution to this java problem:

```
(import (com.fasterxml.jackson.databind ObjectMapper))
(import (java.util Map))
(into {} (.. (ObjectMapper.) (convertValue (Insets. 1 2 3 4) Map)))
=> {"top" 1, "left" 2, "bottom" 3, "right" 4}
```

Answer (score -2):

```
user=> (defn parser [text]
  "{ :items { \"itemid\" 55 }}");Mock
user=> (let [parse-tree (read-string (parser "Abracadabra"))]
((parse-tree :items) "itemid"))
55
```

Comment: Could you explain this?  I don't understand how this solves my problem.

Comment: if your Parser output clojure map format string , use read-string, you can convert.

Comment: This has nothing to do with the question.